# simple question about error cannot read property in javascript

Tags: javascript

From [this codewars exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-encryption-number-1-alternating-split/train/javascript), I've written the following code:

```
function encrypt(text, n) {
    if(n <= 0) {
        return text;
    }
    let en = text.split('');
    for(let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        let odd = [];
        let even = [];

        en.forEach((el,i,arr) => {
            if(i % 2 === 0) {
                odd.push(el);
            } else {
                even.push(el);
            }
        })
        en = even.concat(odd);
    }
    return en.join('');
}

function decrypt(encryptedText, n) {
    if(n <= 0) {
        return encryptedText;
    }
    let de = encryptedText.split('')
    for(let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        let newArr = [];
        de.forEach((el,i,arr) => {
                i < Math.floor(arr.length/2) ? 
                    newArr[2*i+1] = el
                : newArr[2*(i-Math.floor(arr.length/2))] = el;
        })
        de = newArr;
    }
    return de.join('');
}
```

The challenge is to encrypt strings by taking every 2nd character and rearranging from the front and decrypting.

When I submitted the above code, I got 57 successes and only 1 failure saying >cannot read property split of null

(I do not know what the input was, and the test name is called null test).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you've shown two functions ... but haven't shown *how you call them*

Comment: on codewars, you can always just add a console log of the parameters, to see what it was called with.

Comment: encrypt(null) If you pass This Value then "cannot read property split of null" Error Will occurs so use some  exception handling

Comment: What exactly was the codewars challenge you were trying to solve, can you link it?

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-encryption-number-1-alternating-split/train/javascript

The first one is encrypting, the other one is decrypting. and I called the function in the code editor when I checked the result on Chrome. but I thought there did not seem console.log() needed in CODEWARS so I did not put the call here on the question. @CertainPerformance/

Comment: Thanks for all of your help and comments! Kind People !

Answer (score 0):

From [the instructions](https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-encryption-number-1-alternating-split/train/javascript):

> For both methods:
>
> If the input-string **is null** or empty return exactly this value!
>
> If n is <= 0 then return the input text.

"exactly this value" is a bit confusing, but what it means is that you need to change the initial test in both functions from

```
if(n <= 0) {
    return text;
}
```

to

```
if(n <= 0 || text === null) {
    return text;
}
```

Since you currently aren't checking if the input is null, the error `cannot read property split of null` will come up if it's null.

Comment: Oh Thanks. I just got why too. Thanks so much for your help !